# Rails 6.1 with Webpacker fails with jQuery 3.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm trying to update our jQuery from `3.6.0` to `3.6.1` within our application using Rails `6.1` with Webpack. We cannot seem to get jQuery loaded after the update. E.g. `$.fn` or `$.get` is undefined.

Here's our configuration

```
# config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const erb =  require('./loaders/erb')
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb)
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
}));
module.exports = environment;
```

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js

import 'core-js/stable'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.$ = global.jQuery = jQuery
```

I've tried several things following the documentation on the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) but that didn't work yet.

I also created a very basic webpage loading jQuery with the script tag which worked fine.